# JQuery Thickbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the JQuery Thickbox extension. Can I use it on div tags and span tags as well or am I limited to anchor tags and html button? If I can use it like that, how?

Comment: From the Thickbox homepage: While Thickbox had its day, it is not maintained any longer, so we recommend you use some alternatives.

    * colorbox
    * jQueryUI Dialog
    * fancybox
    * DOM window
    * shadowbox.js

-The Management. 9.30.2009 (and Paul Irish)

Comment: It's a internal project I'm working on and do not care if Thickbox is supported or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');//pass where to apply thickbox`

This line you can select the elements which the ThickBox get's applied to.

Comment: Ah, you are a tick faster than me +1 :)

Comment: Ok, did it and seems to work but how can I get the link to open, I only get a preloader, here's my code <span class="thickbox" onclick="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=colorPickBox">Open Thickbox</span